convert static on click event to dynamic MVC
I have a static href link which when click its do some scripts action and work fine but when move code to dynamic MVC its run complication error how to turn it to dynamic MVC as the below static code
<a href="javascript:;" class="collapse-icon flex h-8 w-8 items-center rounded-full transition duration-300 hover:bg-gray-500/10 rtl:rotate-180 dark:text-white-light dark:hover:bg-dark-light/10" @click="$store.app.toggleSidebar()">
                                <svg class="m-auto h-5 w-5" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                    <path d="M13 19L7 12L13 5" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
                                    <path opacity="0.5" d="M16.9998 19L10.9998 12L16.9998 5" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"></path>
                                </svg>
                            </a>


Is it Vue syntax? for MVC Razor syntax you may need @onclick

yes but in old MVC its run compiler error

For MVC Razor use onclick. For Vue use click
